# is it bad idea to change component state including deep copy process frequently in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Multiple Input]

```
inputChange(item, value, key) {
  const list = this.state.list.slice();
  list.find(obj => obj._id === item._id)[key] = value;
  this.setState({ list });
}
```

There are many inputs row by row.

list data are saved in component's state and setState is called whenever inputs change.

And for immutability, list is always deep copied before setState is called.

Isn't it too heavy to deep copy a whole list and call setState everytime inputs change ?

There can be hundreds of rows.

I think list can be divided by rows and saved to state row by row.

But i'm not sure if it is a good design or not...

how do you think about it?

Comment: Quote code **as code**, not as a *picture* of code.

Comment: Also put the correct tags. nodejs seems irrelevant here. Instead, put ecmascript6

Comment: You don't seem to do a "deep" copy which would involve creating new instances for each row, right? The only row affected is the one passed a new value. So all good. Only thing I see is that you should probably use the setState( state => { return { new state }}) pattern (check docs).

Comment: Thanks i'll check it ! Thanks for all of you